# Wedge and Sphere problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A sphere of radius $R$ is in contact with a wedge. The point of contact is $\frac{R}{5}$ from the ground as shown in figure. Wedge is moving with velocity $20~\text{m/s}$ towards left then the velocity of the sphere at this instant will be
>
> [image]

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=513&t=530952

I have attempted a solution there , however , unable to make any progress . Kindly advice if that is the right path to the solution , if something is there that I am not considering.

Comment: Minor comment: The link (v1) looks prone to future [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: @nonagon https://www.google.com.au/search?q=link+rot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wedge is tangent to the sphere. Using that it touches at height R/5 you can easily work out the slope of the wedge. The velocity of the sphere follows directly (20m/s times slope).

Comment: how ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Assume for the moment that R=5 (it doesn't matter for the slope), so the circle is given by x^2 + y^2 = 25. Because height=R/5 we are looking for the slope of the tangent line through the point with y=-4, which is (-3,-4). Now the slope is given by -x/y = -3/4.

Now, given a velocity of 20m/s to the left, we know that the sphere will have a velocity of 3/4 * 20m/s = 15m/s.

I hope that's clear.

Comment: What physical law are you applying here ?

Comment: Nothing but the fact that the wedge won't move inside the sphere.

Comment: so using that , how did you come to the conclusion velocity = slope  x 20 m/s. I can't figure that thing out

Comment: I am still not able to understand ? Can you please elaborate .

Comment: Let's say the height of the intersection of the wedge and the circle at a given time is h, and the wedge moves over axis x. We know the slope of the sphere is 3/4, so dh/dx=3/4, dh=3/4*dx. The velocity of the wedge is given by dx/dt=20m/s. The velocity of the sphere is given by dh/dt. We know dh/dt = 3/4*dx/dt = 3/4*20m/s = 15m/s.